# How to ensure sequence of functions calling in a Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Is there anyway to control the sequence of function calls in a excel sheet when it is re-opened ? Excel automatically re-evaluate the functions when it restarts, where I need to ensure one of my function set is called before another set of function calls.

Thank You

Comment: Are you trying to schedule the execution of in-cell functions, or VBA functions in a module?

Comment: I'm trying to schedule the execution of in-cell functions

Comment: You have to be careful trying to do this, even with a carefully constructed set of false dependencies. For example, UDFs can be evaluated more than once during a recalc. I think Excel generally allows itself to assume that your functions don't have side effects that make the order of execution significant. See http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsj.htm for more information. I think the answer from Knox about putting your initialization code in a Workbook_Open event is the better approach.

Comment: @nimo I realize this was 9 years ago, but I'm curious how you made out. I recently asked on the Excel Community Forums if the excel IF formula guaranteed short-circuit evaluation, and the answer I got was, "Yes." https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Excel/Is-IF-true-false-conditions-non-strict-or-strictly-evaluated/m-p/925609 - I'm not relying on such behavior in my programs, was just using it to help rule out a couple of theories as to a bug I was seeing in a spreadsheet I took over ownership of at work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a fake dependency, so Excel constructs the dependency tree to suit your needs.

For example, if you need A1 to be calculated previously to A2 enter a formula in A2 that is dependent on A1

```
 A2 = Your_Previous_formula() + A1 - A1
```

So Excel will try to calculate A1 first

I assume that your formulas reference external objects or applications. If there is a REAL inverse dependency currently in your cells you will create circular references.

Comment: bit ugly :), but seem to be this is the acceptable answer. thank you

Comment: Agree about the ugly part ... but you're trying to tweak the Excel behaviour :)

Comment: This seems very unsafe and reliant on undocumented behavior, as explained by @jtolle here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052804/how-to-ensure-sequence-of-functions-calling-in-a-excel-sheet#comment3127735_3052804

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you create a subroutine named Workbook_Open()
It will run when you open the spreadsheet and you can call your subroutines that need to run first there.  You obviously can exactly control the order of execution.

Comment: I can not do this since I'm trying to control sequence execution of in-cell functions

Comment: @nimo how did Dr. belisarius's hack work out for you?